# How to render different partials depending on current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got index.erb and index-de.erb, and somewhere I saw an example where this resulted in index-de being rendered when I18n.locale was :de, but i just tried and it did not work and I could not find any documentation on this subject. So does this actually work or do I need an extra plugin for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they must be named index.LOCALE.EXTENSION so e.g. index.de.erb or index.de.html.erb for de locale (I18n.locale)

Answer (score 1):

Localization is built into rails as of 2.2; you'll probably want to check out the [i18n screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n) and/or the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Edit: in particular check out the guide's section 3.3, "Localized Views".  The short answer is that the correct filename is index.de.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in from 2022 (Rails 7). Views and partials in Ruby on Rails with a specific locale are picked automatically.

So when `I18n.locale` is set to `it` and rendering `show`, it will first look for `show.it.html.erb` before `show.html.erb`.

When you have a layout that renders multiple languages (eg. something that happens in a CMS) you can temporarily change the locale with `I18n.with_locale`:

```rb
<% I18n.with_locale(:it) do %>
  <%= render(partial 'header') %>
<% end %>
```